# If both are available, include PDF or EPS?

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps

I'm using GraphPad Prism to generate several graphs. It can export them in some formats, including EPS and PDF. Both are vectorized, both can be implemented in Latex.

So which format is better, and why? PDF seems to be smaller, but the files are sub-megabyte sizes, so I don't care. Is PDF faster, as EPS is implemented (and apparently transcribed to PDF) via epstopdf?

Comment: `.pdf` files are smaller most times, but `.eps` files can be 'understood' ;-)

Comment: @AndrewCashner latex+dvips can't include pdf by default

Comment: use EPS if using latex+dvips., PDF if using pdftex

Comment: If you plan to use `pdflatex`, generating EPS would be a waste of time, as it will be converted to PDF

Comment: @ChristianHupfer what do you mean by "they can be understood"? By whom?

Comment: @firefrog: `.eps` files are readable, the `.ps` code is pure ASCII text. This is not the case for `.pdf` files

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is if the pdf is not compressed ;-)

Comment: @PaulGessler: What have compression ever done for us ;-)